# What is effect of wifi signal for the health?

Tags: side-effects, health-education

Wifi signal course for health effect. According to researches, it is effect for men's sperm to lost the strength of it. I want to know about that issue in deep?

Link:

[Can Wi-Fi Kill Your Sperm?](http://www.menshealth.com.sg/health/can-wi-fi-kill-your-sperm/)

Comment: Welcome.  Where did you find information suggesting there is a correlation? On this site you need to include the research you have done so far to try to answer your question.  There is sparse information on this topic.

Comment: I edit question with evidence. Please help me to sort it out the issue.

Comment: There are also plenty of reports which say the opposite